# Forcing autoscaled consumers to read whole Kafka topic each time they start

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a compacted table repsenting actual state of the system. According to business rules, whenever an instance of service (autoscaled) starts, entire topic should be read and cached into memory along with keepying an eye on newly comming  updates. What are correct Kafka consumer settings in order to guarantee such behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, most importantly is to start the consumer with `auto.offset.reset=earliest`, so you receive the entire topic content up to now and also wait for new events.
Kafka Consumer works in a repetitive polling manner inside a loop, polling (receiving) all the data currently in the topic may demand several polls and take some time, depends on the topic's size (also affected by retention).
About the caching, you'll write to cache the received events in every poll iteration.

Further reading about Kafka Consumer and poll best practices:
https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/kafka-the-definitive/9781491936153/ch04.html